# one bounded and one 0 is 0

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be sequences of real numbers. If $\{b_n\}$ is bounded and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ , then:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_nb_n = 0$$

I tried it as $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = n$
and $b_n = 1/N$

then

$$N-n \leq \epsilon$$

$$a_nb_n = n/N = n-n /(N-n)  = 0/\epsilon = 0$$

How to prove this?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? You **don't** downvote a question just because the OP's stated attempt to solve the problem is flawed. After all, we WANT the OP to tell us what he has tried. You should remove your downvote by upvoting, and explain in a comment of what it is you disapprove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{b_n\}$ is bounded, define $M=\sup\{|b_n|\}$. Then, it holds that

$$-M|a_n|\leq b_n a_n\leq M |a_n|$$

and you have bounded your sequence by a multiple of a sequence that converges to zero. Proof is not far now.

Comment: Technically, you should have $M=\sup_n|b_n|$ as the maximum may not exist. Otherwise correct, +1 for you.

Comment: Thanks for a reminder. As a physicist, I treat max of an infinite sequence as an alias for sup. Fixing to calm down math people :)

Comment: Understandable, I sometimes do the same, but it's a little sloppy technically speaking, and can lead to incorrect results on occasion. Of course, it's completely clear what was intended. My inner Spock couldn't let it go unnoticed, I'm afraid. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As $(b_n)_n$ is limited, it follows that $\exists M>0$ such that $|b_n|\leq M$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Furthermore, as $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=0$, it follows that
$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists n_0\in \mathbb{N} \text{  such that  } \forall n\geq n_0 \Rightarrow |a_n|<\frac{\varepsilon}{M}. $$
Then,
$$|a_n\cdot b_n|=|a_n|\cdot |b_n|<\frac{\varepsilon}{M}\cdot M=\varepsilon, $$
i.e., 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n\cdot b_n =0. $$

Comment: this is the method i think of but i did not know how to write it properly

Comment: Ok, I have helped you.

Comment: but is this right approach?

Comment: but an should choose like $N / M$ , N >$\varepsilon$. then an is still approach to 0 but it end up with N if follow your approach